# Is there a better way to terminate iterator.forEachRemaining

Tags: java, java-stream

I wrote the following code

```
 List<Integer> ll = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.forEach(n1 -> {
        numbers.iterator().forEachRemaining((Consumer<? super Integer>) n2 -> {
            numbers.iterator().forEachRemaining((Consumer<? super Integer>) n3 -> {
                if (n1 + n2 + n3 == 1234)
                    ll.addAll(Arrays.asList(n1,n2,n3));
                    throw new RuntimeException("elements found");
            });
        });
    });
```

i try to find 3 elements in an array, which build a sum of 1234. Is there a better way, to terminate the last forEachRemaining? Is there maybe a better solution, with stream Api, **without using three for loops(i,j,k)**?

Edit: since i got much feedback, this code is only for educational purpose (better understanding of stream and iterator). This is not the way to solve the problem (find three elements in an array that build the sum of 1234). I assumed that forEachRemaining will prevent duplicate sum of elements in array- I was wrong, lesson learned.

Comment: Sure, use "enchanced-for", since you dont want to do something for `each remaining` but only for `some of remaining`

Comment: With this approach for (int n : numbers) {
            for (int n1 : numbers) {
                for (int n2 : numbers) {
                    if (n + n1 + n2 == 1234)
                        ll.addAll(Arrays.asList(n, n1, n2));
                }
            }

        } i get all the combinations back

Comment: *FYI:* `numbers.iterator().forEachRemaining()` does exactly the same as `numbers.forEach()`, i.e. it iterates over **all** the elements in `numbers`.

Comment: *FYI:* The shown code will only examine the first element, then terminate everything, since the `throw` is unconditional, regardless of what the bad indentations might indicate.

Comment: *"without using three for loops(i,j,k)?"* But you are using 3 for loops, you're just using the stream variant instead of a native Java `for` loop.

Comment: @tembers just do `return` where you are throwing exception now.

Comment: @Antoniossss Huh? The code is returning right there anyway, since that's the end of the lambda expression block. Explicitly writing a `return` statement changes nothing, doesn't in any way stop the iteration over values.

Comment: @Andreas especially if you actually apply my first comment.

Comment: @Antoniossss But I can't do that, since OP specifically said *"without using 3 `for` loops (i,j,k)"*, which also invalidates your answer.

Comment: @Andreas thank you i was missing the part, that since i dont use iterator.next, foreachremainig() will do the same as forEach() and iterate over each element each time

Comment: Because doing things simple way is somehow worst than implementing overcomplicated solution? I think otherwise.

Comment: I guess OP falsely expects the `.forEachRemaining()` protects from duplicate count the same element into sum. The `[600,34]` is good counterexample of sample input where this approach, as well as `flatMap`-based approach, fails.

Comment: @Antoniossss Of course, we all do, but the question really is: How to do this using streams, i.e. without using `for` loops. Whether it's a good idea to do that is besides the point, OP is looking for alternatives, e.g. as a learning exercise.

Comment: thank you all, as Tomáš Záluský wrote, I was assuming that .forEachRemaining will protect from the duplicate count, but i was wrong since i dont use iterator.next . @Antoniossss I know that simple is better and I also know how to use nested loops, my intention was to discover and learn something new- even if in this case it is not the best way to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do must to solve it using streams (which I consider reasonable only for educational purposes), you have to stream over indices, not elements. Otherwise duplicate elements leak as false result as I shown in comment under question.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(34);
        numbers.add(600);
        numbers.add(600);
        int[] result = IntStream.range(0, numbers.size()).boxed()
                .flatMap(first -> IntStream.range(0, numbers.size()).filter(second -> second != first).boxed()
                        .flatMap(second -> IntStream.range(0, numbers.size()).filter(third -> third != second && third != first).boxed()
                                .map(third -> new int[] {numbers.get(first), numbers.get(second), numbers.get(third)})
                                .filter(arr -> IntStream.of(arr).sum() == 1234)
                        )
                )
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));        
    }
```

Everybody who advise you to use plain old for loop (no matter whatever SO rule is violated) is right. Just use it. Streams are powerful concept but for different kind of task than yours.

Comment: thank you, as you allready wrote, I assumed that forEachRemaining will prevent duplicate elements in sum.

Comment: Mind that `a + b + c = a + c + b = b + a + c = b + c + a = c + a + b = c + b + a` You don’t need to test all combinations. When you exclude already tested summands from the ranges in the first place, you don’t need to `filter` afterwards. And the innermost `boxed() .map(…` can be replaced by `mapToObj(…`. Putting it together: `IntStream.range(0, numbers.size()).boxed() .flatMap(first -> IntStream.range(first + 1, numbers.size()).boxed() .flatMap(second -> IntStream.range(second + 1, numbers.size()) .mapToObj(third -> new int[] {numbers.get(first), numbers.get(second), numbers.get(third)}) …`

Comment: @Holger *Ad commutativity:* yes, algorithm can be optimized in many better ways than mine, for purpose of showing inappropriateness of stream-based solution I considered it unnecessary. Anyway good point. *Ad mapToObj:* you're right. In first version I tried to solve problem with `IntStream` everywhere (which was impossible unless `flatMapToObj` or equivalent workaround was implemented). Then I chose boxing `IntStream` into `Stream` of `Integer`s. Thanks for simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like

```
List<Integer> doYourThingWith(List<Integer> numbers) {
    for (Integer n1 : numbers) {
        for (Integer n2 : numbers) {
            for (Integer n3 : numbers) {
                if (yourConditionIsTrue) return Arrays.asList(n1, n2, n3);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

....
List<Integer> result=doYourThingWith(yourSetOfNumbers);
```

Comment: This answer is in direct contradiction with the question, which says *"without using 3 `for` loops (i,j,k)"*, so an answer that uses 3 `for` loops is **not useful**, OP already knows it can be done that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```java
List<Integer> ll = numbers.stream()
    .flatMap(a -> numbers.stream()
        .flatMap(b -> numbers.stream()
            .filter(c -> a + b + c == 1234)
            .map(c -> Arrays.asList(a, b, c))
        )
    )
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```